# Boot-repair ubuntu windows8.1 error code Oxc0000225

Tags: boot, windows-8, boot-repair

Windows 8.1 was installed on my hard drive.
I've installed Ubuntu next to it, deleted it and now got it installed on my 32GB SSD (which was partly used by Intel Rapid Storage tech - raid stuff)
After reboot i got into windows repair which hanged.
Now i get error code Oxc0000225 saying i need to repair the pc. From this menu, I can't enter bios options, neither boot loader priority options, neither repair pc (F8).
When i unplug my hard drive, i can get into Ubuntu, bios menu and boot loader priority options.

How do I fix this (automatic boot repair didn't solve it) so that i can get on windows again.

my pc: HP envy 6 1150-eb

Boot-repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6521584/
(also 'repair windows boot files' option is greyed-out)

Answer (score 0):

I would try disconnecting the Ubuntu disk for now, booting from a Win 7/8/8.1 install disk to get to a command prompt, and trying what is described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

That would hopefully repair your Windows boot.

After that, try booting with both discs (maybe set BIOS to specifically boot from the Ubuntu HD) and repair grub (perhaps with this link (http://tipsfromgeek.com/2012/07/how-to-restore-grub-bootloader-after-a-new-windows-installation.html)
If you can't make it boot to Ubuntu with both discs attached, try a boot from a live disc, as described in the link

Sidenote: perhaps Secure Boot is messing with you. If all else fails, try all this again, with Secure Boot disabled

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, I wiped out all the widows stuff and am running Ubuntu fine now.
The issue was probably the windows bootloader. After unplugging the harddrive with the corrupted windows i was able to run from a windows 8 usb recovery stick. After replugging the drive I ran 'repair start-up' which failed. Maybe the only solution was doing it by command promp from the usb stick and run bootrec.exe ..
Thanks anyway for answering.